# Issue splitting an array for use in another array

Tags: php, mysql, variables, for-loop

I have some data, which i currently have hard coded, basically i am trying to split the numbers, 1-port and recreate it as

```
'INSERT INTO '.$tbl_name.'(PortNumber) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(145),(146),(147),(148),(149),(150),(151),(152),(153),(154),(155),(156)';
```

and etc.. i have a pretty good start i think..

PHP

```
//post vars 
$port = 24; //(int)$_POST['ports'];
$super = 2; //(int)$_POST['super'];
$col = 12; //(int)$_POST['columns'];
$row = 2; //(int)$_POST['rows'];
//rest of vars
$halfPort=$port/2;//12
$colHalf = $col / $super;//6
$half=$colHalf-1;//5
$count=1;
$and=1;
$one=1;

echo "<h1>here goes nothen</h1><br><br>";
//sperate port
$finalArray = array();
for ($i = $port; $i >= 1; $i -= $colHalf) {
    $tempArray = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $colHalf; $j++) {
        $tempArray[] = $i - $j;
    }
    $tempArray[]= sort($tempArray);
    $finalArray[] = implode(",", $tempArray);
}
$finalArray = array_reverse($finalArray);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($finalArray, true) . "</pre>";

echo "<br><br>";
//sql for insert
$sqlinsert='
        INSERT INTO '.$tbl_name2.'
        (PortNumber) VALUES ';
 $start='(';
 $end=')';
//preset b
$b=0;
for($c = $port; $c >= 1; $c -= $colHalf) {
    $queryStart = array();
$queryStart[]=explode(',',$finalArray[$b]);
   echo "<pre>" ."start". print_r($queryStart, true) . "</pre>";
    for($s=0; $s<6; $s+=$and) {
        $queryEnd = array();
        $queryEnd[] = $start.$queryStart[$s].$end;
                echo "<pre>" ."end". print_r($queryEnd, true) . "</pre>";
    }
$b+=1;
}
```

to view it live insert it here: http://phptester.net/index.php?lang=en
baisaclly it gets to `$queryEnd`, everything goes down hill, any ideas?

Comment: You might want to state your question a bit more clearly, I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but if you just want to build something like the INSERT query you can do something like:

```
$tbl_name = '?';
echo 'INSERT INTO '.$tbl_name.'(PortNumber) VALUES ('.implode('),(', array_merge(range(1,12),range(145,156))).')';
```

Comment: I think i understand, somewhat, and if i understand right, this will work. But what exactly does the range() function do? and where exactly are those numbers coming from?

Comment: You can lookup the code above in the PHP documentation if you are unsure about a function used, but basically there is range(1,12) that creates an array with elements from 1 to 12 (same for 145 to 156), array_merge combines these two arrays into one and implode creates a string representation of all the elements of this array and glues them together with ),( like 1),(2),(3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see it.  You are reinitializing your $queryEnd array every time the For loop runs.  Move that out of the For loop.
Mike